# Why is the output different in SQL Server and same in Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Why is the output of below two queries is different in SQL Server and same in Oracle ?

```
SELECT 20.0/-2.0/5

SELECT 20/(-2.0)/5
```

Comment: What **is** the output, and what are you expecting instead??

Comment: @marc_s I get `-50.000000000` and `-2.00000000` respectively in SQL Server 2008, but would expect them both to just be `-50.000000000`.

Comment: Note that both give -2 in MySQL

Comment: This shows one important thing: This question is purely academic. I would consider this code in an actual program to be a bug, because it is very unclear what is meant, because `(20/-2.0)/5` is something else than `20/(-2.0/5)`. Use parentheses.

Comment: @praveen: It depends on whether the expression is executed from left to right or from right to left. MySql seems to execute it from left to right, Oracle from right to left. And in SQL-Server, the parentheses around `2.0` seem to change the direction by increasing the precedence of the first division.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth  :Thanks for the clarification

Comment: In SQL Anywhere, both queries give -2 as the answer, FYI.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not agree with your statement that the output should be the same.
If you ask me what 20/-2/5 much output, I will answer you that it could output -2 or -50, depends on implementation details.

[In Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm#i1004611), the only thing you know is that operators '*' and '/' are evaluated before '+' and '-'. But that's all. I don't find any documentation on the priority gives to operator '*' and '/' between themselves.
Since the two query gives -2, you can assume that the parenthesis are left over, and the calculation is made from left to right.

[In SQL Server, the docs specified that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

> When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence
>   level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the
>   expression.

So this computation is conform to the specs :

```
20/2/5 = (20/2)/5 = 2
```

Now add the minus sign

```
20/-2/5 = 20/(-2/5) = -50
```

Add parenthesis again

```
20/(-2)/5 = (20/-2)/5 = -2
```

So not only the parenthesis change the order, but the minus sign too.

In fact, the result should be considered as Undefined, and you can't rely on it.
Add some parenthesis for having a well defined result and prevent headache.

Comment: I'd expect it to differ between RDBMSs depending on implementation, but not for the parentheses to result in a different result in the same RDBMS.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Why not? As it is basically undefined, other factors - like added parentheses - can very well change the outcome. Also see my latest comment on your question.